# google map with async, what wrong?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have an async task which I am trying to add map markers to a google map in android. I set up my map and call the async task with this:

class detail_objek

```java
public void onClick(View v) {  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "anda memilih maps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(), maps.class);
                in.putExtra("currentlatitude",filelatitude);
            in.putExtra("currentlongitude", filelongitude);
                startActivity(in);

}
```

I get an async error in this code:

class maps

```java
public class maps extends FragmentActivity {
    String filelongitude,
            filelatitude;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LatLng userLocation;
    Double destLatitude, destLongitude;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    initMap();

    Intent in = getIntent();
    filelatitude = in.getStringExtra("latitude");
    filelongitude = in.getStringExtra("longitude");

    new DownloadList().execute();
}

public class DownloadList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(maps.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Tunggu Sebentar...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        destLatitude = Double.parseDouble(filelatitude);
        destLongitude = Double.parseDouble(filelongitude);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        addMarkerToMap(new LatLng(destLatitude, destLongitude), false);
        searchLocation();
    }
}
```

The map was working up until now; I didn't do anything map related with the code.

I tried to regenerate a debug key on the google console, change the permissions, etc., but I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filelatitude = in.getStringExtra("latitude");
filelongitude = in.getStringExtra("longitude");
```

You are trying to get a String from intent's extra, when you need a double. I'm assuming that in `in.putExtra("currentlatitude",filelatitude);`  filelatitude is a double. Another error is that you specify wrong key. You put extra with key "currentlatitude" and try to get data with "latitude".

Change your code to be like this:
`filelatitude = in.getDoubleExtra("currentlatitude");
 filelongitude = in.getDoubleExtra("currentlongitude");`

P.S - try to use static final fields for keys

Comment: in.putExtra("currentlatitude",filelatitude); difference class with filelatitude = in.getStringExtra("latitude");

Comment: I don't think you understand me correctly,  in first class you have in.putExtra("currentlatitude",filelatitude); and in second class you have in.getStringExtra("longitude"); . First of all, you must use the same KEY, second of all you must get the right data. Ex: intent.putExtra(KEY, object), intent.getExtra(KEY).

Comment: You're welcome, my answer was the correct solution for you please accept the answer